# Binary Search Tree Best Fit Alg.: Incorrect Output

Tags: c++, find, binary-search-tree, bin-packing, best-fit

**DISCLAIMER:** This is for an school assignment

Hey, all. I've been toiling away at this Bin Packing program for a fortnight and I have one last hurdle to go over: the find function of my Binary Search Tree is giving me incorrect results.

**BinarySearchTree.cpp**

```
#include "BinarySearchTree.h"

void BinarySearchTree::insert(int capacity, int binNumber)
{
    // Insert the Pair into the tree. Overwrite existing
    // pair, if any, with same key.
    // find place to insert
    BinaryTreeNode *p = root,
                         *pp = NULL;
    while (p != NULL)
    {// examine p->capacity
        pp = p;
        // move p to a child
        if (capacity <= p->capacity)
            p = p->leftChild;
        else
            p = p->rightChild;
    }

    // get a node for the Pair and attach to pp
    BinaryTreeNode *newNode = new BinaryTreeNode (capacity, binNumber);
    if (root != NULL) // the tree is not empty
        if (capacity <= pp->capacity)
            pp->leftChild = newNode;
        else
            pp->rightChild = newNode;
    else
        root = newNode; // insertion into empty tree
    treeSize++;
}

void BinarySearchTree::erase(BinaryTreeNode *n)
{
    // Delete the pair, if any, whose key equals n.

    // search for node with key theKey
    BinaryTreeNode *p = root,
                         *pp = NULL;
    while (p != NULL && p->capacity != n->capacity)
    {// move to a child of p
        pp = p;
        if (n->capacity < p->capacity)
            p = p->leftChild;
        else
            p = p->rightChild;
    }
    if (p == NULL)
        return; // no pair with key theKey

    // restructure tree
    // handle case when p has two children
    if (p->leftChild != NULL && p->rightChild != NULL)
    {// two children
        // convert to zero or one child case
        // find largest element in left subtree of p
        BinaryTreeNode *s = p->leftChild,
                *ps = p;  // parent of s
        while (s->rightChild != NULL)
        {// move to larger element
            ps = s;
            s = s->rightChild;
        }

        // move largest from s to p, can't do a simple move
        // p->capacity= s->capacity as key is const
        BinaryTreeNode *q = new BinaryTreeNode (s->capacity,s->binNumber, p->leftChild, p->rightChild, p->parent);
        if (pp == NULL)
            root = q;
        else if (p == pp->leftChild)
            pp->leftChild = q;
        else
            pp->rightChild = q;
        if (ps == p) pp = q;
        else pp = ps;
        delete p;
        p = s;
    }

    // p has at most one child
    // save child pointer in c
    BinaryTreeNode *c;
    if (p->leftChild != NULL)
        c = p->leftChild;
    else
        c = p->rightChild;

    // delete p
    if (p == root)
        root = c;
    else
    {// is p left or right child of pp?
        if (p == pp->leftChild)
            pp->leftChild = c;
        else pp->rightChild = c;
    }
    treeSize--;
    delete p;
}

BinaryTreeNode* BinarySearchTree::find(const int objectSize) const
{
    // Return pointer to pair with smallest key >= objectSize.
    // Return NULL if no element has key >= objectSize.
    BinaryTreeNode *currentNode = root,
                   *bestElement = NULL; // element with smallest key
                                     // >= theKey found so far

    // search the tree
    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        // is currentNode->capacity a candidate?
        if (currentNode->capacity >= objectSize)
        {
            // smaller keys in left subtree only
            bestElement = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode->leftChild;

        }
        else if (currentNode->capacity < objectSize)
        {
            // no, currentNode->capacity is too small
            // try right subtree

            currentNode = currentNode->rightChild;
        }
    }
    return bestElement;
}
```

**BinaryTreeNode.h**

```
struct BinaryTreeNode
{
    public:
        BinaryTreeNode *leftChild;
        BinaryTreeNode *rightChild;
        BinaryTreeNode *parent;
        int capacity;
        int binNumber;

        BinaryTreeNode() {leftChild = rightChild = parent = NULL;}
        BinaryTreeNode(const int& c, const int& b):capacity(c), binNumber(b)
        {
            leftChild = rightChild = parent = NULL;
        }
        BinaryTreeNode(const int& c, const int& b, BinaryTreeNode* l, BinaryTreeNode* r, BinaryTreeNode* p):capacity(c), binNumber(b)
        {
            leftChild = l;
            rightChild = r;
            parent = p;
        }
};
```

**BinPacking.cpp**

```
void BinPacking::bestFitPack(int *objectSize, int numberOfObjects, int binCapacity)
{// Output best-fit packing into bins of size binCapacity.
 // objectSize[1:numberOfObjects] are the object sizes.
   int n = numberOfObjects;
   int binsUsed = 0;
   BinarySearchTree theTree;  // tree of bin capacities
   BinaryTreeNode theBin;

   // pack objects one by one
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {// pack object i
      // find best bin
       BinaryTreeNode *bestBin = theTree.find(objectSize[i]);
      if (bestBin == NULL)
      {// no bin large enough, start a new bin
         theBin.capacity = binCapacity;
         theBin.binNumber = ++binsUsed;
      }
      else
      {// remove best bin from theTree
         theBin = *bestBin;
         theTree.erase(bestBin);
      }

      cout << "Pack object " << i << " in bin " << theBin.binNumber << endl;

      // insert bin in tree unless bin is full
      theBin.capacity -= objectSize[i];
      if (theBin.capacity > 0)
         theTree.insert(theBin.capacity, theBin.binNumber);
   }
}
```

**User Input into main (not shown)**

```
# of objects = 12
Bin capacity = 6

Sizes of objects:
object 1  = 2 
object 2  = 5
object 3  = 5
object 4  = 1
object 5  = 1
object 6  = 3
object 7  = 4
object 8  = 6
object 9  = 2
object 10 = 5
object 11 = 6
object 12 = 1
```

**Expected Output**

```
Pack object 1 in bin 1 
Pack object 2 in bin 2 
Pack object 3 in bin 3 
Pack object 4 in bin 2 
Pack object 5 in bin 3 
Pack object 6 in bin 1 
Pack object 7 in bin 4 
Pack object 8 in bin 5 
Pack object 9 in bin 4 
Pack object 10 in bin 6 
Pack object 11 in bin 7 
Pack object 12 in bin 1
```

**Current Output**

```
Pack object 1 in bin 1 
Pack object 2 in bin 2 
Pack object 3 in bin 3 
Pack object 4 in bin 3 
Pack object 5 in bin 3 
Pack object 6 in bin 1 
Pack object 7 in bin 4 
Pack object 8 in bin 5 
Pack object 9 in bin 4 
Pack object 10 in bin 6 
Pack object 11 in bin 7 
Pack object 12 in bin 6
```

I know I'm close to being done with this assignment. I know what the problem is, but I haven't been able to fix it. Please, will you help me?

Comment: You have no logic to establish the "best element".  You're only returning a non-empty node when it's an exact match.  How does your code function at all when the object size doesn't match the initial bin size?  And what do you do when you decide to pack something in a bin?  Its size changes and so its position in the tree also needs to change.

Comment: I actually just realized I had an old version of my code up. I've just revised it. The output has been updated as well.

Comment: Ok, your search looks fine now.  But, what do you do once you allocate an object to a bin?  The remaining capacity of the bin decreases, and so the location of the bin in the search tree needs to change.  You haven't shown us what you do after you `find()` a node.

Comment: Ok, I just added my best fit algorithm, which shows what happens after a node is found.

Comment: That looks promising.  What does `erase` do, and `insert` for that matter?

Comment: So I put in the rest of the functions I have from BinarySearchTree.cpp in my latest edit.

Comment: Is `p->capacity != n->capacity` really what you want, when you're erasing a specific node?  A node's right-most left child could have the same capacity value as the node, so you could be erasing a different node than the one you intend to erase...  Your BST allows duplicate capacity values, you you really ought to be comparing binNumbers or pointers, not capacities.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be here in your code, in the `erase()`:

```
while (p != NULL && p->capacity != n->capacity)
{// move to a child of p
    pp = p;
    if (n->capacity < p->capacity)
        p = p->leftChild;
    else
        p = p->rightChild;
}
```

Because you're passing in a specific node to erase, and because multiple bins in the tree can have the same current remaining capacity, and because your "best bin" logic returns the last, best match in your recursion, your `erase()` function can `erase()` the wrong node and in fact is likely to.  (If your match code always returned the first "best match," I'm not certain you'd have a problem here, although the code would be fragile.)

This wouldn't actually be an issue if bins with equal capacity are truly indistinguishable.  However, each bin in your code has a unique `binNumber`, and so you get a disconnect between what bin you say you allocated into and what bin you actually erased and reinserted.

Since you're passing in a pointer to an element of the tree, you should just go ahead and do a direct pointer compare here.

```
while (p != n)
{// move to a child of p
    pp = p;
    if (p->capacity >= N->capacity)
        p = p->leftChild;
    else
        p = p->rightChild;
}
```

Erasing a node that is not in the tree is illegal anyway, so the only valid termination condition is that you found the node.

Once you've found the node to erase, the following pseudo-code should correctly rotate the tree:

```
if (pp->capacity >= n->capacity)
    parent_to_me = &pp->leftChild;
else
    parent_to_me = &pp->rightChild;

if (!node->leftChild && !node->rightChild)
{
    // point to nothing
    *parent_to_me = NULL;
} else if (node->leftChild)
{
    if (!node->rightChild)
    {
        // left child, but no right child:
        // promote left child to self
        *parent_to_me = node->leftChild;
    } else
    {
        // left and right children:  Make right child the
        // right child of the right-most left sub-child.
        // Replace myself with left child.
        Node *rmlsc = node->leftChild;

        while (rmlsc->rightChild)
            rmlsc = rmlsc->rightChild;

        rmlsc->rightChild = node->rightChild;

        *parent_to_me = node->leftChild;
    }
} else
    *parent_to_me = node->rightChild;
```

Comment: The first 3 objects are packed, but then it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: Ok, now I need to look more closely at the rest of your erase code.  I see you're allocating a new element in there, which should never be necessary.  It's always a "rotation".  You have to find the right decendent to rotate into the position of the element being deleted.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to put some pseudo-code up above for how you should be handling the "rotation" when you delete a key.  It's pseudo-code, and you'll have to recast it into your own program.

Comment: I'll use this pseudo-code and, hopefully, this thing will be resolved.

I appreciate all your help on this, Joe Z.

Comment: Hopefully the pseudo-code makes sense.  You should be able to draw out diagrams and see how it works.

Comment: I noticed a minor error above, which I will correct.  It *happens* to work, but not for the right reasons.  Specifically, the `if` that checked if both children were `NULL` should be connected to the rest of the code by an `else`.  The way it's written, the final `else` would kick in and also end up assigning a `NULL` in `parent_to_me`, but for the wrong reason.